# How can I prevent duplicate db queries when using Django's inclusion tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So imagine if I have widget that I registered as an inclusion tag like this:

```py
@register.inclusion_tag('tags/widget.html', takes_context=True)
def widget(context):

    return {'qs': Foo.objects.all(),
            'request': context['request'],}
```

In the widget template I loop over some entries in the Foo object. I include the widget in my Mega Menu and my Footer. These templates are obviously split up. And included in `base.html`

However right now when I load the main page I hit the database twice for the same widget (Menu and Footer) so I get a duplicate query. How can I prevent something like this?

I like the idea of the inclusion tag but I don't want duplicate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your tag in `base.html` and save the data that it returns and then pass it to other sub templates that might need that data.

But i don't think you can use `inclusion_tag` anymore. You probably need to use something like `simple_tag`. Here is an example:

**simple_tag:**

```
@register.simple_tag
def widget(some_data):
    return Foo.objects.all()
```

**base template:**

```
# You can access the result as foo_objs
{% widget some_data as foo_objs %}

# pass the data to other templates:
{% include "menu.html" with foo_objs=foo_objs %}
{% include "footer.html" with foo_objs=foo_objs %}
```

Now the widget function called once and data can be passed around.

[Django docs on include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include)